# Cucumber plug in for Eclipse fails to install

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

Happens with both Marketplace and Install New Software
Error
Thu Aug 31 15:24:19 EDT 2023
Missing requirement: Cucumber Editor 2.0.0.202308161613 (io.cucumber.eclipse.editor 2.0.0.202308161613) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.ui.trace 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I have tried marketplace, install new software and drag and drop.  Same error with each method.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens due to firewall issue. You can download the plugin from github and install. Follow the below steps,

1. Go to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse
2. Click on release

   [image]
3. Download the plugin.

   [image]
4. Go to Eclipse -> Help -> Install new software -> Click on 'Add' -> Click on Archive -> Select the plugin location -> Click open -> Click ok.
5. Once it's done. Restart your eclipse.

Comment: The same error occurs when I use the cucumber zip file to install through archive.

Comment: Ensure that you are using a version of Eclipse that is compatible with the version of Cucumber Editor you are trying to install. Consider updating to the latest stable version of Eclipse.

Comment: Install Missing Dependencies:

1. Go to Help > Eclipse Marketplace.
2. Click on Go to the full Eclipse Marketplace link.
3. Use the search functionality to look for Eclipse Trace Framework (ETF) or org.eclipse.ui.trace.
If found, install the appropriate plugin that contains the required bundle.